# Force a page to reload using a query string

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a *simple* way to force a page to reload using a query string?

I've constructed a low bandwidth version of a website activating via a url `foo.com/?il_light_mode=on and foo.com/?il_light_mode=off` it works successfully but I'm having some difficulty in getting the browser to reload the page when the user clicks an activation link.

---

Update
A hacky but workable solution is setting the history to 0 `foo.com/?il_light_mode=on&javascript:history.go(0) and foo.com/?il_light_mode=off&javascript:history.go(0)` but it has the obvious disadvantage of rendering the back button history useless.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "reload using querystring". As far as I know there's no way to do this, and you would need to use some sort of PHP or JavaScript to actually do the redirect. Or an HTML meta refresh.

Comment: I don't quite understand.. Can we see some code?

Comment: @trnelson no he don't... actually html has a reload function build in, but it reloads in time.... `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://de.selfhtml.org/">` (loads http://de.selfhtml.org/ after 5 sec) this can also redirect. But still this question is unclear because OP don't say what user has to do for reload.

Comment: If you could provide the HTML that you're using to set the querystrings then we would be in a better position to provide a working resolution..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, on the very top use something like this:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['il_light_mode'])) {
    // DO YOUR ACTIONS
    header("Location: http://foo.com");
    exit;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understend correctly, then you're looking for [`header`](http://php.net/header):

```
// based on the il_light_mode query parameter check, if light mode should be enabled
$turn_light_mode_on = (isset($_GET['il_light_mode']) and $_GET['il_light_mode'] == 'on') ? true : false;
// redirect to the light version if so
if ($turn_light_mode_on) {
    header('Location: index_light.php');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the current query string and if it matches your need, finally use `window.location.href = url;`

PS: A non-javascript solution is not possible in my opinion